# lock appending slice,no lock reading, so i can get the new length, but no element?

Tags: go, append, slice

when i wrote golang parallel benchmarks for some real codes,i got 1 error.

For example, the variable f will be nil in the func 1,why?

```golang
type foo struct {
    name string
}

var s []*foo
```

race func 1:

```golang
for {
    // no lock
    length := len(s) // typo, it should be len(s) - 1
    f := s[length]
    fmt.Println(f.name)
}
```

race func 2:

```golang
for {
    // lock
    mu.Lock()
    s = append(s, &foo{})
    mu.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: There is a data race on the slice `s`.  Reads in Func 1 can execute concurrently with writes in Func 2.  Use the mutex in Func 1.

Comment: so, i got the real new length,but when i access the element, the element has not be writen yet?

Comment: Ignoring data races, s[len(s)] will always panic. Because there's no synchronization, Func 1 can observe partial updates from Func 2, no updates from Func 2 or inconsistent updates from Func 2.  It's a data race. Any number of things can happen because of compiler optimization, processor caches, etc.

Comment: sorry,it should be s[len(s)-1].thanks for comment

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: i mean when the slice is always growing and we don't lock the reading, is there a possible that we can access the last slot, but get nil

Comment: If you don't lock the reads *anything* can happen. Literally anything. Because it's undefined behavior. There is no point in trying to understand or predict the outcome of code with race conditions. I suggest you read the classic article ["Benign Data Races: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?"](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html)

Comment: Thanks for Sharing

Answer (score 1):

mutexes does not affect calls between locks and unlocks (they do not become atomic, thats not possible for all operations), mutex is what prevents data race but you have to use it for reading and writing and you have to use same instance of mutex on both sides. So this code is safe:

```
type SyncSlice struct {
    inner []int
    m     sync.Mutex
}

func (s *SyncSlice) Append(elem int) {
    s.m.Lock()
    s.inner = append(s.inner, elem)
    s.m.Unlock()
}

func (s *SyncSlice) Len() int {
    s.m.Lock()
    defer s.m.Unlock() // as we have to unlock after returning
    return len(s.inner)
}

func (s *SyncSlice) Get(i int) int {
    s.m.Lock()
    defer s.m.Unlock() // as we have to unlock after returning
    return s.inner[i]
}

func (s *SyncSlice) Set(i, value int) {
    s.m.Lock()
    s.inner[i] = value
    s.m.Unlock()
}
```

Though it is safe only if you use methods and not fields directly. You also have to use same instance of slice, so gorotines have to have acces to pointer of SyncSlice